# C++ B-Tree serialization/deserialization

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, serialization, c++20

Yesterday I wrote a serialization/deserialization for [my B-Tree library](https://github.com/frozenca/BTree/tree/f4d36eca61de3614fdeae36bef1041d8022c617e).

Since the code for whole tree is too large to upload here, I'll upload only serialization/deserialization and node class definition/tree class member variable parts here.

I think my code is not broken, but I want to know how to do error checks better

Type checks:

```
template <typename T>
concept DiskAllocable = std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T> &&
    std::is_trivially_copyable_v<T> &&(sizeof(T) % alignof(T) == 0);

// ...

static constexpr bool is_disk_ = DiskAllocable<V>;
```

Serialization/deserialization:

```
  // serialization and deserialization

  static constexpr std::uint64_t begin_code = 0x6567696e; // 'begin'
  static constexpr std::uint64_t end_code = 0x656e64;     // 'end'

  // for tree, we write a root height

  // for each node, we only read/write two information:
  // 1. number of keys (attr_t, int32)
  // 2. byte stream for key data (sizeof(V) * nkeys())

  // all other information can be inferred during tree traversal

  // number of max bytes for serializing/deserializing a single node
  static constexpr std::size_t keydata_size = sizeof(V) * disk_max_nkeys;

  // maximum possible height for B-Tree
  // if height exceeds this value, this means that serialization/deserialization
  // size will exceed 16TB, much more likely a user mistake or a malicious
  // attack
  static constexpr std::size_t max_possible_height =
      (44UL - std::bit_width(static_cast<std::size_t>(2 * Fanout))) /
      std::bit_width(keydata_size);

  friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is,
                                  BTreeBase &tree) requires(is_disk_) {
    std::uint64_t tree_code = 0;
    if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tree_code), sizeof(std::uint64_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: begin code parse error\n";
      return is;
    }
    if (tree_code != begin_code) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: begin code is invalid\n";
      return is;
    }

    attr_t tree_height = 0;
    if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tree_height), sizeof(attr_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: tree height parse error\n";
      return is;
    }
    if (static_cast<std::size_t>(tree_height) > max_possible_height) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: height is invalid\n";
      return is;
    }

    auto node = tree.root_.get();
    assert(node);

    if (!tree.deserialize_node(is, node, 0, tree_height)) {
      return is;
    }
    if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tree_code), sizeof(std::uint64_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: end code parse error\n";
      tree.clear();
      return is;
    }
    if (tree_code != end_code) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: end code is invalid\n";
      tree.clear();
      return is;
    }
    tree.set_begin();
    assert(tree.verify());
    return is;
  }

  // preorder DFS traversal
  bool deserialize_node(std::istream &is, Node *node, attr_t node_index,
                        attr_t node_height) requires(is_disk_) {
    assert(node);
    node->index_ = node_index;
    node->height_ = node_height;
    if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&node->num_keys_), sizeof(attr_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: nkeys parse error\n";
      return false;
    }
    if (node->num_keys_ >= 2 * Fanout ||
        (node != root_.get() && node->num_keys_ < Fanout - 1) ||
        node->num_keys_ < 0) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: nkeys is invalid\n";
      return false;
    }
    if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(node->keys_.data()),
                 static_cast<std::size_t>(node->num_keys_) * sizeof(V))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: key data read error\n";
      return false;
    }
    node->size_ = node->num_keys_;
    if (node_height > 0) {
      node->children_.reserve(2 * Fanout);
      node->children_.resize(node->num_keys_ + 1);
      for (attr_t i = 0; i <= node->num_keys_; ++i) {
        node->children_[i] = std::make_unique<Node>(alloc_);
        node->children_[i]->parent_ = node;
        if (!deserialize_node(is, node->children_[i].get(), i,
                              node_height - 1)) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    if (node->parent_) {
      node->parent_->size_ += node->size_;
    }
    return true;
  }

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os,
                                  const BTreeBase &tree) requires(is_disk_) {
    std::uint64_t tree_code = begin_code;
    if (!os.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tree_code),
                  sizeof(std::uint64_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree serialization: begin code write error\n";
      return os;
    }

    attr_t tree_height = tree.height();
    if (!os.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tree_height), sizeof(attr_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree serialization: tree height write error\n";
      return os;
    }

    auto node = tree.root_.get();
    assert(node);

    if (!tree.serialize_node(os, node)) {
      return os;
    }
    tree_code = end_code;
    if (!os.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tree_code),
                  sizeof(std::uint64_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree serialization: end code write error\n";
      return os;
    }
    return os;
  }

  // preorder DFS traversal
  bool serialize_node(std::ostream &os, const Node *node) const
      requires(is_disk_) {
    assert(node);
    if (!os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&node->num_keys_),
                  sizeof(attr_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree serialization: nkeys write error\n";
      return false;
    }
    if (!os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(node->keys_.data()),
                  static_cast<std::size_t>(node->num_keys_) * sizeof(V))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree serialization: key data write error\n";
      return false;
    }
    if (node->height_ > 0) {
      for (attr_t i = 0; i <= node->num_keys_; ++i) {
        if (!serialize_node(os, node->children_[i].get())) {
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Node definition:

```
struct Node {
    using keys_type = std::conditional_t<is_disk_, std::span<V, disk_max_nkeys>,
                                         std::vector<V, Alloc>>;

    // invariant: except root, t - 1 <= #(key) <= 2 * t - 1
    // invariant: for root, 0 <= #(key) <= 2 * t - 1
    // invariant: keys are sorted
    // invariant: for internal nodes, t <= #(child) == (#(key) + 1)) <= 2 * t
    // invariant: for root, 0 <= #(child) == (#(key) + 1)) <= 2 * t
    // invariant: for leaves, 0 == #(child)
    // invariant: child_0 <= key_0 <= child_1 <= ... <=  key_(N - 1) <= child_N
    [[no_unique_address]] Alloc alloc_;
    keys_type keys_;
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Node>> children_;
    Node *parent_ = nullptr;
    attr_t size_ = 0; // number of keys in the subtree (not keys in this node)
    attr_t index_ = 0;
    attr_t height_ = 0;
    attr_t num_keys_ =
        0; // number of keys in this node, used only for disk variant

    // can throw bad_alloc
    explicit Node(Alloc &alloc, bool is_leaf = true) requires(is_disk_)
        : alloc_{alloc},
          keys_(alloc_.allocate(disk_max_nkeys), disk_max_nkeys) {}

    ~Node() {
      if constexpr (is_disk_) {
        alloc_.deallocate(keys_.data(), disk_max_nkeys);
      }
    }

    Node(const Node &node) = delete;
    Node &operator=(const Node &node) = delete;
    Node(Node &&node) = delete;
    Node &operator=(Node &&node) = delete;

    // ... unrelated details ...
  };
```

Tree class members

```
private:
  [[no_unique_address]] Alloc alloc_;
  std::unique_ptr<Node> root_;
  const_iterator_type begin_;
```

Test code:

```
#include "fc_btree.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  namespace fc = frozenca;
  fc::BTreeSet<int> btree_out;

  constexpr int n = 100;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    btree_out.insert(i);
  }
  {
    std::ofstream ofs{"btree.bin", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary |
                                       std::ios_base::trunc};
    ofs << btree_out;
  }

  fc::BTreeSet<int> btree_in;
  {
    std::ifstream ifs{"btree.bin", std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::binary};
    ifs >> btree_in;
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (!btree_in.contains(i)) {
      std::cout << "deserialized tree key lookup failed\n";
    }
  }
  std::cout << "OK\n";
}
```

[The code for the entire tree class](https://github.com/frozenca/BTree/blob/f4d36eca61de3614fdeae36bef1041d8022c617e/fc_btree.h)

Feel free to comment anything!

Answer (score 2):

Self answer: the code above missed something.

When a read from an input stream succeeds but the value is invalid, the reader has a duty to mark `std::ios_base::failbit` to the input stream, so that the `operator bool()` of the input stream is `false` where `is >> tree` is evaluated.

So the code should be like this:

```
    if (!is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tree_code), sizeof(std::uint64_t))) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: begin code parse error\n";
      return is;
    }
    if (tree_code != begin_code) {
      std::cerr << "Tree deserialization: begin code is invalid\n";
      is.clear(std::ios_base::failbit); // should set failbit
      return is;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Throughout the code, I miss documentation:
What are the functions specified to return?
Why would deserialisation replicate the tree structure serialised,
instead of constructing a "suitably balanced" tree?

As a test, I think checking iteration results would be stronger than *just contains*.
Consider checking "the Multies".

Comment: Balancedness and tree invariants are already being checked in the line ```assert(tree.verify());``` at the end of deserialization, but yes, it is a good catch

Comment: `assert(tree.verify()); at the end of deserialization` is a white-box insight. And I doubt either that or *contains* would catch getting multiplicities wrong.

Comment: counting multiplicities is ```count()```, it is supported for ```BTreeMultiSet```, ```BTreeSet``` doesn't allow duplicates. But yes, I'll add tests for that. Actually there are four types, ```BTreeSet```, ```BTreeMap```, ```BTreeMultiSet``` and ```BTreeMultiMap```. I'll ban possible conversions via serialization/deserialization between different types

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick one: in the error cases we stream to `std::cerr`.  That's not always the most appropriate response (e.g. in a GUI program).  We should be using a logging library (so we can send to syslog) and/or providing reasonably complete information to the caller (perhaps in a suitable exception) in order to handle it more sensibly.

---

Another quickie:

> ```
> is.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tree_code), sizeof(std::uint64_t))
> ```

Probably clearer to write `sizeof treecode`, rather than requiring the reader to match the type.